# Avoiding Cartesian product in PostgreSQL with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create a training app in python to work with a database of movies, adding movie details via a text menu prompting user input for all fields (movie name, actors, company, etc.).

I am using PostgreSQL as the database and import psycopg2 in Python. In the database, I use a many-to-many relationship (since the same actor can star in several movies, and so on). Therefore, I have a **movies** table (*movie_id, name, company, year*), an **actors** table (*actor_id, last_name, first_name, actor_ordinal*), and the third intermediary table **actors_movies** (*actor_id, movie_id*) foreign keys to join the two, with **(actor_id, movie_id)** made the primary key.

Then I have this code in Python (it is the ultimate stage of a user inputting their data via the text interface):

```
def insert_movie(name, actors, company, year):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='postgres', database='movie')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query1 = "INSERT INTO movies (name, company, year) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
    cursor.execute(query1, (name, company, year))
    query2 = 'INSERT INTO actors (last_name, first_name, actor_ordinal) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
    cursor.executemany(query2, [tuple(actor) for actor in actors])
    query3 = 'INSERT INTO actors_movies (actor_id, movie_id) SELECT actor_id, movie_id FROM actors, movies ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'
    cursor.execute(query3)

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

It works fine for query1 and query2. But query3 (which targets the intermediary **actors_movies** table) duplicates all data. Every time I add a new movie, in the intermediary table it features all actors from other movies, e.g. (after joining):

```
movie_id    movie_name    actor_id
1           The Matrix    1
1           The Matrix    2
1           The Matrix    3
1           The Matrix    4
2           Titanic       1
2           Titanic       2
2           Titanic       3
2           Titanic       4
3           Patriot       1
3           Patriot       2
3           Patriot       3
3           Patriot       4
```

So, this is completely wrong, as, according to this table, all the four actors featured in all the three films, which is false.
Why does it occur this way and how can this problem be eliminated? I cannot find any option to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a distinct on select clause of third query which will remove duplicate.
While inserting related data into multiple table, maintain some keys for eg: movie will have movie_id which can be referred in actors table Then use that key to join movie and actor table.

Answer (score 0):

This is how relational databases work. With your third query, you are doing a cartesian join on the two tables (actors and movies), since you did not provide a constraint on which to apply the join. So, the only thing that the database can do, is to assign to each record of table A, all the records in table B.

This concept is illustrated, from a formal (mathematical) point of view, at the following wikipedia page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Tutorialspoint also has a nice example and explanation that may be useful to understand what your problem is

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

### TL;DR

In order to avoid the cartesian join when inserting new values, you'll have to insert them manually, or apply a condition after joining the two tables (actors and movies), like the one below

INSERT INTO actors_movies (actor_id, movie_id) SELECT actor_id, movie_id FROM actors, movies WHERE actors.id + movies.id < 4;

Comment: How can I apply this condition, if the number can be different from 4? For instance, a user can add 6 movies with 60 actors, and then 20 more.

Comment: I guess your is just some random data for populating and testing the database, right? In production, you'll need the reference movie, i.e. movie's id, and the reference actor, actor's id. Then you'll record the <actor-id, movie-id> in the table. Otherwise, you may filter the name of the movie and the name of the actors in the WHERE clause

Comment: Well, yes, it is a database populated with random data (from my own input, just for testing). All actors have their id's, and all movies have their id's. And I have created a third, intermediary, table for joining the two and creating a many-to-many relationship. I still don't get at all how the WHERE clause might help there.

Comment: The WHERE clause can be used to filter the data, making it closer to what a real case scenario may look like. Also, if it's just random data, then either you populate it with the exact values, or you insert the data making the joins, but it is much more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how exact data can be inserted? I guess that this is right my problem. The id's of both books and authors are populated automatically as serials, so I can't bear them all in mind. There should be some simple way to code it, but I don't know it.

Comment: Simply use a new INSERT query, where you clearly state the id of both actors and movies (since you should reset the database every time, reset also the serials of both books and movies).
Otherwise, use queries like "INSERT INTO actors_movies (actor_id, movie_id) SELECT actor_id, movie_id FROM actors, movies WHERE (actors.name="Keanu Reeves" OR actors.name="Laurence Fishburne") AND movie.name="The Matrix"